# Understanding shap_values() function in determing what machine learning model is doing

Tags: python, machine-learning, shap

I'm currently following a tutorial on determining why my machine learning model made its predictions by using the "shap" python package

I'm not fully sure however what is happening in the following code `shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X=X_test[:1])`

I understand that I am looking for shap_values on the first row of my test data, however what does this mean?

In the tutorial, they have nsamples, and l1_reg also passed into .shap_values and I'm not sure what either of these parameters do. Could someone explain simply what these parameters are used for as everything online is a little too low level for my understanding.

I have 1270 features and my model is a sklearn SVC model if this would aid in explaining the nsamples parameter

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Comment: @desertnaut It's specifically asking about a python package and refers to specific methods in said python package, so I don't see how it's not about programming?

Comment: What does this *mean* is not a programming question. Moreover, please notice that what "these" parameters are used for without an actual sample & example *here* arguably lacks details and it is way too broad a question. All these are actual (and different) reasons for closing it.